# Azure Active Directory Consent Framework not kicking in for .NET client application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have a Web API running in an Azure Web App. It is used from a .NET WinForms client application. In the same Azure Web App, there is also an ASP.NET MVC site.

Users authenticate to the site and the .NET client using Azure AD credentials. This should be multi-tenant. The MVC app works fine multi-tenant, but I have trouble getting the client to run multi-tenant.

My understanding from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-integrating-applications is that the Consent Framework should kick in automatically if OAuth 2.0 is used. I am using code (below) that is very close to the sample at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-multitenant-windows-store/.

While I can successfully log in with a user in the tenant where the native app is defined and use the app, I cannot use the app with a user from another tenant. There is no consent asked and I get an AdalException:

```
AADSTS50001: The application named https://<myurl> was not found in the tenant named <sometenant>.onmicrosoft.com.  This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant.  You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
Trace ID: 3<snip>2
Correlation ID: 2<snip>a
Timestamp: 2017-01-05 01:01:10Z
```

I have added the ID of the native client app to the list of `knownClientApplications` in the web app's manifest. I am authenticating against the "common" tenant (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common). The third-party tenant user account signing in is a Global Admin in that tenant.

So, I am clearly overlooking something to enable the Consent Framework but I can't find what it is based on the sample...

Relevant native client code below

```
Uri RedirectUri = new Uri(sRedirectUri);
// AadInstance is the common tenant
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AadInstance);

try
{
    PlatformParameters pp = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto);
    // Authenticate to Azure AD
    Program.WebApiAuthenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(WebAppIdUri, ClientID, RedirectUri, pp);
    return true;
}
catch (AdalException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Log In Not Successful");
}
```

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to reproduce this issue however failed. The scenario that native client app consume the web API which both protect by Azure works well when I login the native app with the multiple tenant account. I tested the code sample from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-multitenant-windows-store).

And based on the error message, it seems that the **resource** is not correct, please ensure it is same as the **APP ID URI** for the web API app you register on Azure. I could get the same error message when I specify an incorrect **resource**.

Comment: If had the incorrect resource, surely it wouldn't work with an account in any tenant? It works with an account from the tenant where the native client app is defined.